# Redirect STDERR separately for the shell and the program

Tags: unix, redirect, shell, stderr

I'm doing some audit automation, this example describes checking the version of Java, even though other programs do the same thing.

The output of "java -version" goes to STDERR, which is easily redirected, but I want to send shell errors (for example, when the java binary is missing) to /dev/null. It seems that shell redirection is an all-or-nothing proposition.

My most promising attempt so far as been:

```
{ /bin/ksh "{java -version 2>&1;}"; } 2>/dev/null
```

...which properly sends the output of the -version command to STDOUT, but if java isn't there, it sends the shell "not found" error to STDOUT as well. I don't want to see that message.

Same behavior with:

```
{ /bin/ksh "{java -version 2>&1;}" 2>/dev/null; }
```

Does anyone know a way to limit the scope of redirection so each process gets its own? I'm not limited to ksh, but for environment reasons it's got to be a shell based one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not possible to check if java is found and executable?

```
test -x "$(which java)" && java -version 2>&1
```

or if you want to get around test and check for java-errors, too

```
java -version 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null && java -version 2>&1
```

Comment: Using "test" is a different, promising approach. That could do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to additional descriptors. This is for bash, I think it works for ksh too:

```
exec 3>javalog
java ... 2>&1 >&3
exec 3>&-
```